# I am not sure why redux isn't recognizing thunk

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux-thunk

I cant figure out what is going on. I have redux-thunk setup just like always. For some reason that I can not figure out I get the error: Error: Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions. can anyone help me figure this error out?

Index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './app';
import './index.css';

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

CreateStore.js

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import reducers   from './reducers';

export default function configureStore(initialState) {
    return createStore(
    reducers, 
    initialState,
    applyMiddleware(thunk)
);
}
```

app.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Routes             from './Routes';
import {Provider} from 'react-redux';
import configureStore from './configureStore';

const store = configureStore();

 class App extends Component {
  render(){
     return (
          <Provider store={store}>
             <Routes/> 
          </Provider>
     );
  }
} 
export default App;
```

Today.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { autoLocate } from '../actions';
import { Button } from './Common'

class Today extends Component {

componentDidMount() {



  this.props.fetchTodayWeather('http://
   api.wunderground.com/api/cc9e7fcca25e2
   ded/geolookup/q/autoip.json');

                    }
  render() {

     return (
     <div> 
         <div style={styles.Layout}>
           <div><Button> HAHAH </Button></div>
           <div><Button> Weather Now </Button></div>
        </div>
     </div> 
    );
  }
}


    const mapStateToProps = state => {
      const loading = state.locate.loading; 
      const located = state.locate.autolocation;         

      return{ loading, located };
    };

    const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
       return {
              fetchTodayWeather:(Url) => dispatch(autoLocate(Url))
      };
    };

export default connect(mapStateToProps,mapDispatchToProps)(Today);`
```

autoLocate.js

```
import { AUTODATA,
        AUTOLOCATING
 } from './types';


export const autoLocate = (url) => {
  return (dispatch) => {
    dispatch({ type: AUTOLOCATING });

     fetch(url)
      .then(data => fetchSuccess(dispatch, data))
  };
 };

 const fetchSuccess = (dispatch, data) => {
   dispatch({
    type: AUTODATA,
    payload: data
  });
};
```

Comment: you're importing autoLocate from ../actions but your post describes it being in autoLocate.js?  if actions.js is exporting all of your actions then please post that file as well.  Other than that everything looks normal.

Comment: I have an index file inside of my actions folder which exports all my actions.  "export * from './autoLocate'; "

Comment: maybe your reducer is not a function / wrongly exported (can't see it here)